# Frame plot axis labels: superscripts and subscripts in italic and non-italic

Tags: plotting, labeling

I want to make nice plot labels with framed  plot.

I need to have labels with both subscripts and superscripts, both of which need to contain italic and non-italic characters.

For example $a_{b, c}^{d, e}$ label on x-axis. How to manipulate so (for example) $b, d$ are italic and $c, e$ non-italic?

My wrong code:

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,6Pi}, Frame->True, FrameLabel->{Style["Subscript[a, b, c]^(d, e)"]}]
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style[Subsuperscript[a, Row[{Style["b", Italic], ", c"}], 
     Row[{Style["d", Italic], ", e"}]], 18]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]